# Actions-On-Google[Permission Intent] Get User Location / Name

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

```
const agent = new WebhookClient({request, response});
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Text, Card, Image, Suggestion, Payload} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');


let payload = {
          "systemIntent": {
            "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
            "data": {
              "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
              "optContext": "To deliver your order",
              "permissions": [
                "NAME",
                "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
              ]
            }
          }
        };
agent.add('PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION');
agent.add(new Payload(PLATFORMS.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE, payload));
```

Simple payload to get UserLocation and Name using the **PERMISSION** intent

The response to the above I get it

> **To deliver your order, I'll need to get your name and street address** 
>   **from Google. Is that ok?**

Follow intent to this intent is also set up with event ***actions_intent_PERMISSION*** in it

I have been trying to solve this for 2 days by trying to fire **actions_intent_PERMISSION** using suggestion chips etc but nothing happens post this ?

Where am I going wrong I am not able to comprehend. There is some silly mistake somewhere - please if someone can point it out - would help a lot.

Thanks

===========EDIT============IMAGES ATTACHED FOR THE INTENTS============

[permissions intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlZm3.png)

[permissions response with event actions_intent_PERMISSION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lppT6.png)

edit: cant embed images because of points. above links are there. thanks

=================================request-response json===================
when the intent permissions is triggered below is the request

```
{
  "responseId": "54a4be35-3d0b-4cc8-b036-46fab0d09361",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "permissions",
    "action": "permissions",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/projectid/agent/intents/95237653-0af0-4d0c-9101-0cd8ee0db186",
      "displayName": "permissions"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {},
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "payload": {}
  },
  "session": "projects/projectid/agent/sessions/13213e7f-dba5-4d0c-979a-f626f7ac4691"
}
```

fulfillment response

```
{
  "conversationToken": "[]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {},
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
          "inputValueData": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
            "permissions": [
              "NAME",
              "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
            ],
            "optContext": "To locate you"
          }
        }
      ],
      "speechBiasingHints": [
        "$name-type",
        "$sports",
        "$gender"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "95237653-0af0-4d0c-9101-0cd8ee0db186"
    }
  }
}
```

The response from simulator for **permissions** intent

> =======================================================================

Issue has been resolved 
Points to note:

1. Actions-on-Google simulator works very weirdly to be trusted upon
   whether your webhook is working or not
2. Promise resolution was an
   issue - agent was waiting for a promise to be resolved before that
   it was getting passed to next time
3. Correct way to test your bot
   is to publish your bot in ALPHA on the assistant directory rather
   than testing on the Simulator because it is very unstable in terms
   of you can never predict its behavior. Will never tell you the
   correct error to be debugged and will abruptly stop working for no
   reason whatsoever

Comment: let payload = {
          "systemIntent": {
            "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
            "**inputValueData**": {
              "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
              "optContext": "To deliver your order",
              "permissions": [
                "NAME",
                "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
              ]
            }
          }
        };                                                              This too doesnt help

Comment: Why are you using the dialog fulfillment library instead of the actions on Google library?

Comment: I am using fulfillment library because I am using the same webhook to response to different platforms e.g. WebApp, Facebook, Assistant and probably Twilio later on. Fulfillment library helps in responding to different clients using custom payload and built-in elements like Cards, Carousels, SimpleResponse, et al

Comment: I have been able to make Suggestions, Cards, RichResponse, CarouselSelect/ListSelect etc all work through custom payloads but somehow cannot comprehend how the Permissions payload is not working. It looks as if the event that is to be triggered by the built-in intent(actions.intent.PERMISSION) is not getting triggered

Comment: Are you setting it as a followup intent or as an intent with the Event set. Can you update your question to show a screen shot of the Intent you are expecting to be triggered? Is it possible that a different Intent, possibly the fallback Intent, is being triggered? If so, can you show the JSON that you're receiving?

Comment: @Prisoner I am attached the images for the same. **permissions** is the original intent and **permissions.response** is the intent with actions_intent_PERMISSION event.

Comment: @PrisonerI have updated the response that I get from the simulator because the webapp doesnt have that PERMISSION intent provoking mechanism. sorry

Comment: @Prisoner problem was with a promise and simulator. Thanks for response

Comment: Can you write that up as an answer in case other people have a similar problem?